# Div keeps sliding to the left

Tags: css, html, position, margin

I have a div that is centered on my website using `margin: auto;`

but for some reason if i start to shrink the width of my browser the div i showed in the image below begisn to move left with the browser, and wont stay in its position. I have tried using the `position:` thing but it doesnt seem to be working for my issue.

How can i get this div to stay centered and not move with the browser?

You can see the issue here on [My Website](http://ifaketext.com/testiframe/)

If you trysh rinking the browser width beyond a certain point that div just begins to move and isnt centered anymore.

Its a problem because people with small resolutions will not see the website right.

The div that seems to be having the issue is `main-frontpage`

[image: My Issue]

Comment: I see it just fine. Which browseR?

Comment: Any browser shrink the width of your browser and youll see it start to move.

Comment: I believe once you are past 1240px it starts to shrink

Comment: Its a problem because people with small resolutions will not see the website right.

Comment: it is not a problem to worry because no one is surfing net in not maximized window and if they are then it's their headache,see the http://google.com , and resize it you will find the same behaviour there also

Comment: But people with small resolutions below 1280 will have an issue, and i dont want to have an issue like this on my website.

Comment: I want to figure it out to keep it clean and as well for future knowledge

Comment: @Random Googles search area still stays centered after a certain width you have shrunk your browser mine doesnt mine moves all the way to the left

Comment: Who would want to have a website that cant be viewed properly in any situation?

Comment: Its just been annoying me for 2 days already i cant figure it out..

Comment: The main problem seems to be that you use a different width-scheme at each block: `min-width` on `#jflow-content-slider`, plain `width` on `footer`, so they have no chance to be in sync.

Answer (score 0):

change to min-width of your #footer to the same as the .jflow-content-slider & #main-frontpage (1050px) and then at least your content slider will not overlap the text at the bottom.

**EDIT:** looking again at your setup, just change the width of your #main-frontpage to the same as #footer #content-wrapper - 1240px. Really this is way too wide and it should be 960px wide but unless you change the width of your footer content this the only way to do it